# python loop won't iterate on second pass

Tags: python, csv

When I run the following in the Python IDLE Shell:

```
f = open(r"H:\Test\test.csv", "rb")
for line in f:
    print line
    #this works fine
```

however, when I run the following for a second time:

```
for line in f:
    print line
    #this does nothing
```

Comment: [This might help](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.tell).

Answer (score 4):

This does not work because you've already seeked to the end of the file the first time. You need to rewind (using `.seek(0)`) or re-open your file.

Some other pointers:

1. Python has a very good [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. Do not attempt to implement CSV parsing yourself unless doing so as an educational exercise.
2. You probably want to open your file in `'rU'` mode, not `'rb'`. `'rU'` is universal newline mode, which will deal with source files coming from platforms with different line endings for you.
3. Use `with` when working with file objects, since it will cleanup the handles for you even in the case of errors. Ex:

.

```
with open(r"H:\Test\test.csv", "rU") as f:
    for line in f:
        ...
```

Comment: good point on using the csv module to read the file. It allowed me to use the list index as well, which was something I needed.

Comment: Is there a similar re-set function for lists? I'm coming across a similar situation where I print the items in a list and it works the first time, but then I enter the same code, and it prints nothing. I have to del the list and re-create it. I'm using python IDLE shell if that matters

Comment: @wannabe_n00b please ask in a separate question and show your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can **read the data from the file in a variable**, and then you can iterate over this data any no. of times you want to in your script. This is better than doing `seek` back and forth.

```
f = open(r"H:\Test\test.csv", "rb")
data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
        print line

for line in data:
        print line
```

Output:

```
# This is test.csv

Line1,This is line 1, there are, some numbers here,321423423

Line2,This is line2 , there are some characters here,sdfdsfdsf

# This is test.csv

Line1,This is line 1, there are, some numbers here,321423423

Line2,This is line2 , there are some characters here,sdfdsfdsf
```

Comment: This depends on the CSV you're loading. Typically, when we're working with CSV files coming from customers, they are are multiple GB in size. A `seek(0)` is very cheap compared to loading it all into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've gone all the way through the CSV file, and the iterator is exhausted. You'll need to re-open it before the second loop.

Comment: using seek(0) is another alternative and should have less overhead (not significant) and avoid read/write concurrency potential problems.