# Pointer to the line is changed when receiving a file from a function in Python (after iterating over it)

Tags: python

I am passing a file to a function and iterating over it .
After getting the file back , My pointer is changed . I assume it is because I passed it as a reference . How can I avoid it and pass it as a "Value" . I went through other examples in Stackover flow , most of them talks about one scenario  only (list.append)  . Here is my code  :

Code passing the file :

```
data = matchpattern(infile , record_read_regex , output_fmt)

for currentline in infile:
#Following line prints the line with pointer shifted ( requirement is to print the first line of the list
  print 'printing the first line of the list in calling function********* ' + currentline
```

Function :

```
def matchpattern(infiles , record_read_regex, output_fmt):
  for line in infiles:
    #Following line prints the first line of the list
    print 'printing the first line in pattern function ' +  line
    m = re.match(record_read_regex, line)
    if m:
      return record_capture
```

Comment: Which pointer is changing ? Do you mean the file pointer - i.e. the last byte that is read - if you think about it, it will be obvious that it will change, as your function is reading the file.

Comment: Just move back to the front of the file before returning from the function.

Comment: Try adding `infile.seek(0)` before returning from your function

Comment: possible duplicate of [python loop won't iterate on second pass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139012/python-loop-wont-iterate-on-second-pass)

Comment: I am talking to the pointer to the row in the file . I have updated the question .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Reading a file does consume data, and this is not necessarily a reversible operation. Disk files are typically [seekable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), however, which allows you to restore the position if you save it:

```
oldpos = infile.tell()
callfunction(infile)
infile.seek(oldpos)
```

It's possible for a file to change between readings, and pipes, sockets, devices etc are not seekable in the first place. In some cases the seeking itself takes a long time to do.